# My script is about as scary as the XML it's reading

Tags: xml, vbscript

This was a revision, made when the code failed after an update (at least that is what I think happened).

So I fixed it and now it works, but I think that this code can be written better and more efficiently, and perhaps made easier to read. Note that VBScript/VBA/VB6 isn't (aren't) my primary language(s), the closest thing I do is C#.

I presume that the `If` statements can be whittled down a little bit, (I *know* they can).

I am unsure of the version/flavor of VB this is, but given that it is written inside `<script>` tags I presume it's VBScript.

```
Public Function GetParameterXml()
  GetParameterXml = _
  "<Parameters>" &_
  "  <Parameter Value='TYPE' Code='T' Description='Type' Type='Combo' Tooltip='Select parameters from the drop down list.'>" &_
  "    <Options>" &_
  "  <Option Code='1' Description='Assignee Name' Value='A' />" &_
  "  <Option Code='2' Description='Creditor Name' Value='C' />" &_
  "  <Option Code='3' Description='Debtor Name' Value='D' />" &_
  "    </Options>" &_
  "  </Parameter>" &_
  "  <Parameter Value='NAMEFORMAT' Code='T' Description='Name Format' Type='Combo' Tooltip='Select parameters from the drop down list.'>" &_
  "    <Options>" &_
  "  <Option Code='11' Description='First Mid Last' Value='1' />" &_
  "  <Option Code='12' Description='Last, First Mid' Value='2' />" &_
  "  <Option Code='13' Description='Last, First' Value='3' />" &_
  "  <Option Code='14' Description='Last, First, Mid' Value='4' />" &_
  "    </Options>" &_
  "  </Parameter>" &_
  "</Parameters>"
End Function

Dim Parameter: Set Parameter = Parameters.Item(Bookmark,"TYPE")
Dim Parameter2: Set Parameter2 = Parameters.Item(Bookmark,"NAMEFORMAT")
Dim sTemp
Dim oNodes: Set oNodes = Nothing
Dim oNode: Set oNode = Nothing
Dim PartyName()
Dim ArrayIndex
Dim varPartyName
Dim FirstName
Dim MidName
Dim LastName
Dim ParameterValue
Dim Suffix
ReturnData = ""

If Parameter2 is Nothing Then
  ParameterValue = "1"
Else 
  ParameterValue = Parameter2.value
End If

ArrayIndex = 0

If Not Parameter is Nothing Then
  Set oNodes = xmlDoc.selectNodes("/Record/CelloXml/Integration/Case/JudgmentEvent/Judgment/Additional/SDMonetaryAward/SDMonetaryAwardParties/SDMonetaryAwardParty[PartyConnection[@Word='"& uCase(parameter.Value) &"']]")

  For each oNode in oNodes
    For each oNode2 in oNode.childNodes
        If oNode2.nodeName = "PartyName" Then
            ReDim Preserve PartyName(ArrayIndex)
            PartyName(ArrayIndex) = oNode2.text
            ArrayIndex = ArrayIndex + 1
        End If
    Next
  Next

  For each varPartyName in PartyName

    dim FirstMiddleName
    LastName = Split(varPartyName, ",")(0)
    FirstMiddleName = Trim(Split(varPartyName,",")(1))
    Suffix = Trim(Split(VarPartyName,",")(2))
    MidName = Trim(Split(FirstMiddleName, " ")(1))
    FirstName = Trim(Split(FirstMiddleName, " ")(0))

    If ParameterValue = "1" Then
      If IsNull(FirstName) and IsNull(MidName) Then
        ReturnData = ReturnData & LastName & Chr(13) & Chr(10)
      ElseIf IsNull(MidName) Then
        If IsNull(Suffix) Then
            ReturnData = ReturnData & FirstName & " " & LastName & Chr(13) & Chr(10)
        Else
            ReturnData = ReturnData & FirstName & " " & LastName & " " & Suffix & Chr(13) & Chr(10)
        End If
      Else
        If IsNull(Suffix) Then
            ReturnData = ReturnData & FirstName & " " & MidName & " " & LastName & Chr(13) & Chr(10)
        Else
            ReturnData = ReturnData & FirstName & " " & MidName & " " & LastName & " " & Suffix & Chr(13) & Chr(10)
        End If
      End If
    ElseIf ParameterValue = "2" Then
      If IsNull(FirstName) and IsNull(MidName) Then
        ReturnData = ReturnData & LastName & Chr(13) & Chr(10)
      ElseIf IsNull(MidName) Then
        If IsNull(Suffix) Then
            ReturnData = ReturnData & LastName & ", " & FirstName & Chr(13) & Chr(10)
        Else
            ReturnData = ReturnData & LastName & ", " & FirstName & " " & Suffix & Chr(13) & Chr(10)
        End If
      Else
        If IsNull(Suffix) Then
            ReturnData = ReturnData & LastName & ", " & FirstName & " " & MidName & Chr(13) & Chr(10)
        Else
            ReturnData = ReturnData & LastName & ", " & FirstName & " " & MidName & " " & Suffix & Chr(13) & Chr(10)
        End If
      End If
    ElseIf ParameterValue = "3" Then
      If IsNull(FirstName) Then
        ReturnData = ReturnData & LastName & Chr(13) & Chr(10)
      Else
        If IsNull(Suffix) Then
            ReturnData = ReturnData & LastName & ", " & FirstName & Chr(13) & Chr(10)
        Else
            ReturnData = ReturnData & LastName & ", " & FirstName & " " & Suffix & Chr(13) & Chr(10)
        End If
      End If
    ElseIf ParameterValue = "4" Then
      If IsNull(FirstName) and IsNull(MidName) Then
        ReturnData = ReturnData & LastName & Chr(13) & Chr(10)
      ElseIf IsNull(MidName) Then
        If IsNull(Suffix) Then
            ReturnData = ReturnData & LastName & ", " & FirstName & Chr(13) & Chr(10)
        Else
            ReturnData = ReturnData & LastName & ", " & FirstName & Suffix & Chr(13) & Chr(10)
        End If
      Else
        If IsNull(Suffix) Then
            ReturnData = ReturnData & LastName & ", " & FirstName & ", " & MidName & Chr(13) & Chr(10)
        Else 
            ReturnData = ReturnData & LastName & ", " & FirstName & " " & Suffix & ", " & MidName & Chr(13) & Chr(10)
        End If
      End If
    End If
    FirstName = Null
    LastName = Null
    MidName = Null
    FirstMiddleName = Null
    Suffix = Null
  Next

End If

Erase PartyName

If Len(ReturnData) > 0 Then
  ReturnData = Left(ReturnData, Len(ReturnData)-2)
End If
```

Again, this is code that I fixed and added to.

Input from the XML for the name comes in this format:

> Johnson, James T, {optional-Suffix}

Comment: Yay, a [cyclomatic complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) party!! I'll look at this when I have a chance :)

Comment: I'll just say that every single `Chr(13) & Chr(10)` in there could very well be replaced with `vbNullString` :)

Comment: I think it is supposed to be a newline character.  this code runs a token that populates on a word document inside of a third party application, lots of fun!  would the `vbNullString` behave like a newline? I guess that might be determined by the rules of the main application too?

Comment: I didn't get very far on that link, sounds like what I have going here though, but I am a little confused.  sounds like some before bed reading to me...lol

Comment: Oh darn, what an epic typo/brainfart! I meant `vbNewLine`!! Sorry!

Comment: `vbNullString` is equivalent to `""`..

Comment: Having spent a little bit more time looking at this code, I'm sorry to say, but this code can't work as is. `IsNull("")`  returns `False`, and `Split("John Doe", " ")(2)` blows up with an *index out of bounds* error - the basic assumptions this code makes, are erroneous... or so it seems. **Unless this is VB.net code and not VBA/VB6?**

Comment: @retailcoder that is probably what this is then.  this Script runs with or without the Middle name and/or the suffix as far as my testing has gone so far.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11301/discussion-between-malachi-and-retailcoder)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming this is VBScript, and I'm not familiar at all with VBScript, and it seems pretty different from VBA/VB6 as far as iterating arrays (can't do `For Each` on an array in VBA/VB6) and string nullability is concerned - and VBA/VB6 isn't exactly crystal-clear as to what means what.

From [this source](http://www.songhaysystem.com/kb/number/950165041/subject/vba) (dates back from 2000, quotes a dead Microsoft link - emphasis & formatting mine):

> - `""`: A **zero-length string** (commonly called an "empty string") is technically a zero-length BSTR that actually uses six bytes of memory. **In general, you should use the constant `vbNullString` instead**, particularly when calling external DLL procedures.
> - `Empty`: A variant of VarType 0 (vbEmpty) **that has not yet been initialized**. Test whether it is "nil" using the `IsEmpty` function.
> - `Nothing`: **Destroys an object reference** using the Set statement. Test whether it is "nil" using the `Is` operator.
> - `Null`: A variant of VarType 1 (vbNull) that means "no valid data" and **generally indicates a database field with no value**. Don't confuse this with a C NULL, which indicates zero. Test whether it is "nil" using the `IsNull` function.
> - `vbNullChar`: A character having a value of zero. It is commonly used for adding a C NULL to a string or for filling a fixed-length string with zeroes.
> - `vbNullString`: A string having a value of zero, such as a C NULL, **that takes no memory**. Use this string for calling external procedures looking for a null pointer to a string. To distinguish between vbNullString and "", use the VBA StrPtr function: **`StrPtr(vbNullString)` is zero, while `StrPtr("")` is a nonzero memory address.**

---

So, it being a *script*, I'm not going to try to go and define classes here, [although it seems to be supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ah5852c(v=vs.84).aspx). I'm still trying to wrap my head around all those conditions!

The conditions (and the fact that they are repeated in all main 4 branches) are actually hiding the intent.

So I would write a little `Coalesce` function and do away with all those checks:

```
 Public Function Coalesce(ByVal value)
     If IsNull(value) Then
         Coalesce = vbNullString
     Else
         Coalesce = CStr(value)
     End If
 End Function
```

You seem to have a fixed amount of possible values for `ParameterValue`, to me this looks like a job for some `Select Case` rather than an `If...ElseIf...ElseIf...` block - also, separate the concerns of figuring out a line's content and of appending it to the result - because it's the `ParameterValue` that determines the order of the names, whether they're present or not doesn't matter, they can all be appended - as long as we ensure to replace `Null` values with non-value `vbNullString`:

```
'note: LastName can't ever be null... unless nothing was supplied at all.
Dim lineResult
Select Case ParameterValue

    Case "1": 
        'First Mid Last [Suffix]
        lineResult = Trim(Coalesce(FirstName) & " " _
                        & Coalesce(MidName) & " " _
                        & Coalesce(LastName) & " " _
                        & Coalesce(Suffix))

    Case "2": 
        'Last, First Mid [Suffix]
        lineResult = Trim(Coalesce(LastName) & ", " _
                        & Coalesce(FirstName) & " " _
                        & Coalesce(MidName) & " " _
                        & Coalesce(Suffix))

    Case "3": 
        'Last, First [Suffix] ~> Middle name ignored?
        lineResult = Trim(Coalesce(LastName) & ", " _
                        & Coalesce(FirstName) & " " _
                        & Coalesce(Suffix))

    Case "4": 
        'Last, First [Suffix], Mid
        lineResult = Trim(Coalesce(LastName) & ", " _
                        & Coalesce(FirstName) & " " _
                        & Coalesce(Suffix) & ", " _
                        & Coalesce(MidName))

End Select
```

This leaves us, in the worst cases, with a `lineResult` that's ended with `", ,"` or `","`. Easy fix - not so neat, but hey between that and a bunch of nested `If` statements, I go with this:

```
If Right(lineResult, 2) = " ," Then lineResult = Left(lineResult, Len(lineResult) - 2)
If Right(lineResult, 1) = "," Then lineResult = Left(lineResult, Len(lineResult) - 1)
```

Now all we're missing is `lineResult = lineResult & vbNewLine`, and then we can do `ReturnData = ReturnData & lineResult`, and then we can iterate again.

Comment: Gotta say I haven't tested any of this, but I'm quite confident you'd get the exact same results as you do now.

Comment: well they want me to take out some of the options for this token, so I will have a chance to change the code again, hopefully the version that this application is using will support the things that you have here, I will check into it and let you know

Comment: otherwise it looks very nice.

Comment: Thanks! I think `Case "3"` could be dropped, it ends up with the same format as `Case "4"` (given #4 would have `Mid` optional) so if you don't have a `MidName` they both output the same result.

Comment: i got pushed to something else, will get back to you on this.

Comment: No worries, I'm on something else too! :)

Comment: Very Elegant, no Bugs yet. now I know when I ask Questions about this it's VBSCRIPT!

Comment: It just occurred to me that you might have doubled-up spaces between name parts in (edge) cases 1 & 2...

Comment: like if the Middle name is missing? I haven't seen anything like that yet.